# Code generation failed on PyQt5 Designer on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I recently started a project in PyQt5, but when I try to view generated code in python, I get an error saying "Unable to launch /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic: execvp: No such file or directory".

[first_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTOKY.png)

I've only found articles about this issue on windows, and the solutions seem not to translate well into Linux.

My versions:
Python 3.9
PyQt5 5.15.2
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I've tried copying the uic file to the error folder, but it generated another error:

"/usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/uic: undefined symbol: _ZdlPvm, version Qt_5"

[second_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHX5L.png)

Comment: You are probably missing a package. Unfortunately I cannot help you with identifying which one. Maybe search for install instructions for your programs and libraries. Maybe python3-pyqt5 or something is missing?

Comment: Do not use Qt Designer to generate the code, because it will create a Pyside2 file. For PyQt5, you must use the [pyuic5 tool](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#pyuic5). (NB: you should also make sure you only install the official Ubuntu PyQt/Qt packages. Do not use pip to install them).